# Toggle on/off rule based labeling in PyQGIS

Tags: python, qgis-3, labeling, pyqgis-3, rule-based

I have a vector layer. It's defined with rule based labeling.

I need to control the rules to turn on / off programmatically.

How to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using QGIS 3.28 on a layer that already has rule based labeling active, this works:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
ruleList = layer.labeling().rootRule().children()
for rule in ruleList:
    if rule.description() == 'my description':  # the description you set for the rule
        rule.setActive(False)  # False turns rule off, True turns rule on
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

If you didn't set a description for all rules, you could also check the filter expression:

```
if rule.filterExpression() == '"feed_type" = 2':
    rule.setActive(False)
```

Another approach could be to use the unique rule identifier obtained by `ruleKey()` on the Rule itself, save a reference to it somewhere and use it later to find the rule again using `findRuleByKey()`, but I haven't tested it. If you would like to dig into it, [check out the API for `QgsRuleBasedLabeling`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsRuleBasedLabeling.html)